# Is there a way to troubleshoot change notifications in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use oracle change notifications (API from Dbms_Change_Notification package) to update complex materialized views. I install change notification for my table with my PL/SQL callback and I can see in USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS view that my change notification is installed properly. On development oracle servers with low load change notifications are called as expected just after commit to observed table. But on real servers with high load it looks like change notifications are never called.

Is there any way to troubleshoot why change notifications are not called, when they are going to be called, what kind of error happens when they are called and so on?

P.S. I am using oracle Version 10.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

On your production system, have you set the JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES initialization parameter? It must be set to a non-zero value.

Has the user registering the queries been granted the right privileges on the production database (CHANGE NOTIFICATION and execute on DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION)?

Comment: I already removed change notifications from my system because it is almost impossible to troubleshoot what goes wrong with them. But yes, my user has both CHANGE NOTIFICATION and EXECUTE ON DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION privileges and JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES was set in non-zero value.